# Integration of complex functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Show that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx=(2n)!\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4^n n!}$ by differentiating the equation $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx^2} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}$.

This is what I proved so far:

By differentiating the given equation I have $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-tx^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} t^{-\frac{3}{2}}$. So, when $t=1$, $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} $. Now I used mathematical induction for the expression I have to prove. I got it for $n=1$. But stucked in proving the rest. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** what appends if you write the $n$th derivative?

Comment: nth derivative of what?

Comment: of RHS and LHS of $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx^2} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}$.